# Comma in string format arguments

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I came across the following implementation of `ToString()` method:

```
return string.Format("${0}.{1,2:00}", dollars, cents);
```

I couldn't understand the 2nd command-line argument used in here i.e. `{1,2:00}`
Could somebody please explain the use of `,` in these arguments?

Answer (score 3):

See documentation [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), and try for example:

```
result = string.Format("We have '{0,6}' with positive", 3.14);

result = string.Format("We have '{0,-6}' with negative", 3.14);
```

Quote from linked page:

> The optional `alignment` component is a signed integer indicating the preferred formatted field width. If the value of `alignment` is less than the length of the formatted string, `alignment` is ignored and the length of the formatted string is used as the field width. The formatted data in the field is right-aligned if `alignment` is positive and left-aligned if `alignment` is negative. If padding is necessary, white space is used. The comma is required if `alignment` is specified.